# ASP.NET MVC AJAX PartialView Telerik UI not loading

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a PartialView which is updated using AJAX. The HTML elements are loaded correctly when updating the Div using AJAX, but the Telerik chart is not loaded. The datasource in the chart is not calling the Action method:

```
.DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("Movies_Read", "Movies")))
```

When the PartialView is initially loaded, not using AJAX, the datasource is calling the action method and the chart is loaded correctly.

According to [Telerik ASP.NET PartialView AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/using-with-partial-views-loaded-via-ajax.html) there needs to be this Javascript call for the OnSuccess event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updatePlaceholder(context) {
    // the HTML output of the partial view
    var html = context.get_data();

    // the DOM element representing the placeholder
    var placeholder = context.get_updateTarget();

    // use jQuery to update the placeholder. It will execute any JavaScript statements
    $(placeholder).html(html);

    // return false to prevent the automatic update of the placeholder
    return false;
}
```

I have tried the javascript mentioned in the documentation, but the get_data() and get_updateTarget() does not exists event though I havde added the MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js. I suspect that these are deprecated.
I have also tried other javascript functions but without any luck.

My AJAX call is:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateMoviesChart", "Movies", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "MoviesDiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "updatePlaceholder", }))
```

How do I load the Telerik Chart correctly when using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

In the view, the following script should be added to update the Div using Ajax:

View:

```
<div class="chart-wrapper"></div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@(Url.Action("Movies_Read", "Movies"))",
            success: function (data) {
                $(".chart-wrapper").html(data);
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Also the controller should be updated to have ActionResult as return type.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult RemotePartialView()
{
    return PartialView("remote_partial_view");
}
```